# Items are not unpublished with Dynamic Component Template

Tags: 2013-sp1-hr1

I have many Components published with a Dynamic Component Template, and I want to update the template to no longer be a dynamic Component Template.

To update the template I must first un-publish all usages of it, makes sense.

I try to un-publish the Component Template, therefore un-publishing all the items using it (which I can see in its Where Used). The items I see in Where Used do not appear in "items to be unpublished" list, which again with a bit of though makes sense.

So, I consider writing a small script to un-publish them all (there are lots), but first try to un-publish a few manually to check they are being removed from the Where Used list.

When I un-publish one of the Components in the Where Used list, I get success in the Publish Queue, but the item does not disappear from the Where Used list.

In both Where used (Component and Component Template) I still see listing for the item, rendered with the Component Template. I also still see the published icon on the Component.

One thing which could be an issue; The Component Template was never limited by Schema

Comment: Are you un-publishing it from ALL the publishing targets (even the ones which are discontinued, if any)?

Comment: Yes. To begin with I am trying to get one item, which I know where it is published to to un-publish

Answer (score 1):

I manage to resolve this by doing the following:

1. Add design Publication as an allowed publication to my Publication Targets
2. Un-publish from design Publication, with include all child publications selected
3. remove design Publication from allowed publications on Publication Targets
4. Set Component Template from "Published as Dynamic Component" to "Published Embedded on a Page"